# Plotly and stat_summary produce "NA" in tooltip

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, plotly, ggplotly

I'd like to use `stat_summary` to show mean values of my data on a ggplot2 graph, and use plotly to show the data and mean values in the tooltip. I'm using the dev version of `ggplot2` (ggplot2_2.2.1.9000) and I just reinstalled `plotly` (plotly_4.7.1).

`stat_smooth` works - you can see I'm hovering over the smoothed line and I get values in the tooltip.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
p <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
ggplotly(p + stat_smooth(se = FALSE))
```

[image]

However, `stat_summary` **doesn't** - and that's what I need for my "real-world" problem :). Note how `Sepal.Width` is `NA`. *I could have sworn this worked for me last year.*

```
ggplotly(p + stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom="line", size = 1))
```

[image: enter enter image description here]

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I didn't!

Comment: Bummer—thanks for the reply.